# Group Specific Rows in RDLC report

Tags: reporting, rdlc

I'm generating this RDLC report and I'm stuck where I need to group specific rows with id values as follows...

[image]

***NOTE:*** I have only added Type ID column just for clear understanding, I will will not use that column in the final report.

It uses a Postgres DB.
In this **Type ID** **1** & **2** are both outgoing types, I have grouped this report by Type ID... But I need the Outgoing records to be grouped as well... 
In other words I need to group Type 1 & 2 and get a single record for outgoing.

eg:

Outgoing    21    00:27:46

Internal    50    00:08:09

Incoming    87    01:42:55

I tried ... 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/group-expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs and used the folllowing...

```
=IIF(First(Fields!information_element.Value)=1 OR First(Fields!information_element.Value)=2,"Outgoing", (iif(Fields!information_element.Value = 4 , "Internal", (iif(Fields!information_element.Value = 5 , "Incoming", ""))  )) )
```

as *Call Type* Column *expression*, where '***information_element***' is Type ID **data field** Name.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Should be tagged as SQL and not c#.

Comment: Is it postgres?..

Comment: @VaoTsun hi yes the DB is in postgres...

Comment: @jdweng tnx for the correction....and corrected...

Comment: @user2994921 sorry - I meant you tag postgres and yet there is no query, no DDL, nothing about postgres

Comment: @VaoTsun I can add the postgres query but i tried to group the result through reporting side than through the query if its possible. 

Comment: no,no - the opposite. if your post has nothing to do with postgres, remove the tag? :) despite the fact you work with postgres - there's nothing about it in the post - right?

Comment: @VaoTsun ah right...  already removed.. thanx

Answer (score 0):

I changed the postgres query itself, I couldn't find a way to do it through reporting side.
What I did was...

```
(case when trim(coalesce(information_element,'0')) = '1' then '2' else trim(coalesce(information_element,'0')) end) as information_element
```

I check the Type ID (*data field* name is 'information_element' ) and if it is 1 I set it to 2.

That's it. :)

Hope this helps someone...